# How to implement this diagram in Python using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to know the actual Python 3 code to create a diagram similar to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0R3PnJEisqk&t=847s.

Sharing the screenshot here as well:
[image]

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) can be used to draw a 2D function. The x and y directions first are created in 1D using e.g. `np.linspace` and are then combined to 2D via `np.meshgrid`. Numpy's [magic](https://unidata.github.io/python-training/workshop/NumPy/numpy-broadcasting-and-vectorization/) allows writing simple expressions which behind the scenes are operating on the complete mesh at once.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 4), gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0.05})
distance, velocity = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1, 50), np.linspace(0, 1, 50))
reward1 = 1 - distance ** 0.4
reward1[distance < 0.1] = -1
reward1[(distance < 0.1) & (velocity < 0.1)] = 1
im1 = ax1.imshow(reward1, origin='bottom', extent=[0, 1, 0, 1], vmin=-1, vmax=1, cmap='bwr',
                 interpolation='nearest')
ax1.set_xlabel('distance')
ax1.set_ylabel('velocity')
plt.colorbar(im1, ax=ax1, shrink=0.9)

dist_reward = 1 - distance ** 0.4
vel_discount = (1 - np.maximum(velocity, 0.1)) ** (1 / np.maximum(distance, 0.1))
reward2 = vel_discount * dist_reward
reward2[distance < 0.1] = -1
reward2[(distance < 0.1) & (velocity < 0.1)] = 1
im2 = ax2.imshow(reward2, origin='bottom', extent=[0, 1, 0, 1], vmin=-1, vmax=1, cmap='bwr',
                 interpolation='nearest')
ax2.set_xlabel('distance')
ax2.set_ylabel('velocity')
plt.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2, shrink=0.9)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]